# Spinner issues in android?

Tags: android, spinner

Why do my spinner shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJtcp.png). I want to display my spinner in normal way. that is the value in my spinner are so small. and doesnt look like normal spinner values.

The Code is here

```
ArrayList<Organization> organizationsarray = new ArrayList<Organization>();
Organization[] users = null ;
 final ArrayList<Organization> organizations = (ArrayList<Organization>)i.getSerializableExtra("organizations");
for( Organization organization : organizations ) {
    Log.d(TAG , " ORGANIZATION RETRIEVED DETAIL :"+ organization ) ;
   }
   users = new Organization[ organizations.size() ] ;
   users = organizations.toArray( users ) ;
Spinner sp = (Spinner) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.brand_spinner).getActionView();
sp.setAdapter(new SpinAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,users));
 sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            value = ((Organization)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getId();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),""+value+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            session.checkLogin();
            HashMap<String, String> usertoken = session.getUserToken();
            Log.d(TAG,"loading token to the temp: " +usertoken.get("token"));
            Log.d(TAG,"loading values to the sharedpref: "+value);
            String tokenvalue = usertoken.get("token");
            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            session.createLoginSession(tokenvalue,value);
             }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Organization class:

```
public class Organization implements Serializable {

private String name;
private Long id;

public Organization(){
}

public Organization(String name, Long id) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    System.out.println("tostring");
    return "name :"+name +"|| id :"+id ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a layout file spinner_text.xml in `layout` folder

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:maxLines="1"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textColor="@color/text_primary" />
```

and change this line

`sp.setAdapter(new SpinAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,users));`

to

```
sp.setAdapter(new SpinAdapter(this,R.layout.spinner_text,users));
```

Comment: it remains same like before no change

Comment: you can increase padding to vary sapaces